# Find out why I am getting network-Wifi Lag on TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, networking, wifi

I have been playing TF2 over wifi on my pc for years without problems with a very low ping. Recently, I started getting lag spikes with the game showing the red "timeout countdown in 30 seconds" message. Usually after about 10 to 15 seconds the message goes away and the game comes back. This did not use to happen at all and I have a good ping and framerate. So far I have not been able to identify what is causing the problem and have tried an number of things like temporarily turning of anti-virus, shutting down services, rebooting right before playing, etc.

Any suggestions for figuring out what is causing this?

Comment: Does it happen if you use a wired connection?

Comment: If I were you I'd check if the router is dying or not.

Comment: I had been wondering that too but switched internet provider (including Wifi) and still having the same issues on the new one.

Answer (score 2):

Does it happen on different servers, official and community? If you can, try playing on the same network and server, but on different device and consider reinstalling your Wi-Fi drivers and updating your operating system.

Comment: Because this is speculative it's not an actual answer, and should've been posted as a comment. Still a good idea though.

Comment: You're correct, but 50 reputation is required for it and as no one mentioned it in the comments I decided to post it as answer.

Comment: Ah, I always forget that. Still seems like a very back-asswards limitation.